# How to get text from menu label in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Recently I am working on project Text Editor using tkinter. I tried to make font menu but I am getting some problem.
[Font Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXaQ8.png)
[Printing Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQWFW.png)

```
from tkinter import *
root= Tk()
def SetFontSize():
    Font[1] = font_size.entrycget(0,'label')
    content_text.config(font=Font)
    print(Font)

def SetFontFace():
    Font[0] = font_face.entrycget(0,'label')
    content_text.config(font=Font)
    print(Font)
menu_bar = Menu(root)
Font = ["Arial", 12]
font_sizes = [10,11,12,14,16,18,20]
font_faces = ["Arial", "Times New Roman", "Helvetica", "Courier", "Star Wars", "Comic Sans MS", "Bahnschrift"]
font_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label='Font', menu=font_menu)
font_size = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
font_face = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
font_menu.add_cascade(label='Font Size', compound='left', menu=font_size)
font_menu.add_cascade(label='Font Face', compound='left', menu=font_face)
font_menu.add_command(label='Font Color', compound='left')
size_var = IntVar()
size_var.set(12)
face_var = StringVar()
face_var.set("Arial")
for k in sorted(font_sizes):
    font_size.add_radiobutton(label=k,compound='left',variable=size_var, command=SetFontSize)

for j in sorted(font_faces):
    font_face.add_radiobutton(label=j,compound='left',variable=face_var, command=SetFontFace)
content_text = Text(root, wrap='word',font=Font)
content_text.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')
root.mainloop()
```

But, it is always selecting only one font size and font face i.e. ["Arial", 10].
Can anyone please help me with this problem.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: If I am selecting any of the font size either 14 or 18, it is always selecting 10. Same goes with font face, it is selecting only Arial.

Comment: so is there an error? or is it more like the code is not working as intended?

Comment: yes it is not working as intended.

Comment: Then what is your question??

Comment: That it is not selecting any other font than 10 and Arial

Comment: According to me it is always selecting first menu. But how to select other fonts?

Comment: @Matiiss he did as you wanted

Comment: @Programmer yep, I didn't notice that for some reason, he actually made a very good case

Comment: You can use `Font[1] = size_var.get()` and `Font[0] = face_var.get()`

Comment: replace: `Font[1] = font_size.entrycget(0,'label')` with `Font[1] = size_var.get()` otherwise what was the point of using an `IntVar()` or `StringVar()`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yeah it is working now. Thanks

Comment: @Matiiss yes now it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in functions and now it is giving expected font.

```
def SetFontSize():
    Font[1] = size_var.get()
    content_text.config(font=Font)
    print(Font)

def SetFontFace():
    Font[0] = face_var.get()
    content_text.config(font=Font)
    print(Font)
```